# How to send file to all the clients connected to the server in C# using NetworksApi.TCP.SERVER

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

here is the SERVER code 
i want to make a online exam system which will send question.txt and rules .txt to all the clients connected to the server. i dont know how to send file ..i want to brows the file from local drive then send the file to all the clients  please help me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NetworksApi.TCP.SERVER;

namespace server
{

    public delegate void show_status(string soneya);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Server examserver;
        string  star_time;
        string finish_time;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void ChangeText(string soneya)
        {

            if (textBox3.InvokeRequired)
            {

                Invoke(new show_status(ChangeText), new object[] { soneya });

            }

            else
            {
                textBox3.Text += soneya + "\r\n";
            }
        }


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != " ")
            {
                examserver = new Server(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);

                examserver.OnClientConnected += new OnConnectedDelegate(examserver_OnClientConnected);

                examserver.OnClientDisconnected += new OnDisconnectedDelegate(examserver_OnClientDisconnected);
                examserver.OnDataReceived += new OnReceivedDelegate(examserver_OnDataReceived);
                examserver.OnServerError += new OnErrorDelegate(examserver_OnServerError);
                examserver.Start();
                ChangeText("server is Running");

            }
        }

        void examserver_OnServerError(object Sender, ErrorArguments R)
        {
            //ChangeText("server is not Running");

        }

        void examserver_OnDataReceived(object Sender, ReceivedArguments R)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void examserver_OnClientDisconnected(object Sender, DisconnectedArguments R)
        {
            ChangeText("disconnected "+ R.Name );

        }
        void examserver_OnClientConnected(object Sender, ConnectedArguments R)
        {
            ChangeText("accepted request from"+R.Name );

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            star_time = textBox4.Text;
            finish_time = textBox5.Text;
            ChangeText("Exam will be Start from" + textBox4.Text);
            ChangeText("Exam will be finish at " + textBox5.Text);

        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the NetworksAPI Library, does not contain a way to "Send" / "Broacast" files. (Either to one User or to Everyone).
Although i believe it is possible if every Client (Works also as Server) and if Server could also work as Client.

Either ways i never tested that, since in my Application i just required to connected my Client to the Server, and communicate with it.

I noticed that you've also got your code from the Video Tutorial.
I made some modifications on my application including adding a method to send file(s) to Server. (Wich is not included on that Tutorial)

I may not Help you 100% in sending a File "Broadcast" (send file to everyone), but i can help you (or anyone who requies a way to do this) into getting a solution to send a file (or Files) from Client to Server.

Check My Tutorial Bellow (Suiting as best as possible to your code / the Standard Tutorial found on the Internet):

"How to send a File From Client to Server" Using NetworksAPI

[On the Client]

1) create a string:

```
string fileName;
```

2) create a Get / Set Method:

```
public string FileName { get { return fileName; } set { fileName = value; } }
```

3) Under the Button "Send_File_Click" (Explanation):

a) Configure your OpenFile Dialog

b) Then Load OpenFileDialog

c) Set the string you created above to OpenFileDialog Selected File

Code Bellow:

```
    private void button_SendFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.CheckFileExists = true;
            ofd.CheckPathExists = true;
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
            ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fileName = ofd.FileName;
                textbox_FileName.Text = FileName;
                c.SendFile(fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

if you want you can add the Transfer Percentage to Your "Status" textBox.

Note: I believe that in the Tutorial (Video) where you got that Code the TextBox

is Called: txt_Chat or txt_Message.

Code Bellow:

```
void c_OnClientFileSending(object Sender, ClientFileSendingArguments R)
{
     try
     {
    /* 
    Set Text stands for the method: "updateText" or "changeText" as referenced in that Tutorial you've seen.
    Included a `String.Format` to Properly Display Percentage.
    */          
     string percentage = String.Format("Transfering: {0}%", R.TransferPercentage); SetText(percentage);
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
     }
```

[On the Server]

1) Inside `"Form1_Load()"` Method you must set your server (Received) Files Path.

Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server.FilesPath = @"C:\";
}
```

That's all M8!

Note that there isn't any message (in my code) that will indicate if the file 
was received or not.

If you've set the `"textbox_Status"` like i mentioned above, you'll notice that it 
will display: "100%" after the file was sent.

just check the (server) received files folder after the transfer is complete.

In this case it will be under   `C:\`

The file will be there.

Best Regards;